# Can you pass generics to .NET Core hardware intrinsics methods?

Tags: c#, .net-core, intrinsics

I'm writing a basic library to experiment with C# hardware intrinsics (`System.Runtime.Intrinsics*` namespaces) and have a method that could support any 'hardware' type (`Byte`, `SByte` ... `UInt64`, `Double`)

When trying to use a generic signature the compiler is unable to work with the generic and cannot choose the correct overload; For example:

```
public static unsafe void GenericSimd<T>(T value, ReadOnlySpan<T> span) where T : unmanaged
{
    fixed (T* fixedSpan = span)
    {
        Vector128<T> vec0 = Vector128.Create(value);       // CS1503, Cannot convert T to byte
        Vector128<T> vec1 = Sse2.LoadVector128(fixedSpan); // CS1503, Cannot convert T* to byte*
    }
}
```

ref: [CS1503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1503)

I think this is due to the [`unmanaged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) constraint allowing additional non-'hardware' types (`Decimal`, `enum` etc.), therefore not being restrictive enough to guarantee an appropriate overload will exist.

Defining an interface to use as an additional constraint alongside `unmanaged` is also unworkable as it would require partial-ing built-in types.

Is there a way to implement this method using generics and avoid writing an overload for each type?

Comment: `dynamic` would probably work, but if you're using SIMD I assume you're not ready to pay for that overhead

Comment: Overload resolution happens at compile time. Since different types use different overloads of `Create`, the compiler cannot pick the *one* overload that's correct to put a call to inside this method. To avoid too much repetition, I'd recommend text templating or the new newness of source generators working from a fixed list of types you need implementations for.

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer to avoid `dynamic` if possible. I hadn't considered source generators though, that ought to work fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can't do that for generics. At least because Vectors have no generic create methods or cast options. But there's an option for `Span<T>`.

```cs
public static unsafe void GenericSimd<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span) 
    where T : struct
{
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes = MemoryMarshal.Cast<T, byte>(span); // no data copy here involved, it's lightning fast
    fixed (byte* fixedSpan = bytes)
    {
        // this way
        Vector128<byte> vec1 = *(Vector128<byte>*)fixedSpan;
        // or this way
        Vector128<byte> vec2 = Sse2.LoadVector128(fixedSpan);
    }
}
```

But ensure that you have enough bytes (16 or more) in `Span` to fill the full `Vector128<byte>`.

Also you may get a size of `T`

```cs
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
```

And then `switch-case` depending on size of the variable. But there's different behavior of handling data needed for integer and floating-point numbers.

A lot of switching logic that's not a friend of SSE/AVX code. At least because it must be as fast as possible but either `switch` or `if`, even `Cast` consumes CPU resources.

I suggest you to make non-generic overloads similar to .NET SSE/AVX methods.

Btw, if you need pure generic hardware-accelerated `Vector<T>` - [welcome to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1?view=netcore-3.1) `System.Numerics.Vectors`. I tested, in most cases it shows the same performance on my Core i7 as Intrinsics.

```
public static void GenericSimd<T>(T value, ReadOnlySpan<T> span)
    where T : struct
{
    Vector<T> vector1 = new Vector<T>(value); // fine
    Vector<T> vector2 = new Vector<T>(span); // also fine
}
```

Also you may check e.g. `Vector<int>.Count` to get the vector's capacity.